# ajax call to web api returning 404 not found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

ajax call to web api returning 404 not found. 
Requested URL: /home/api/DeveloperApi/. 
I havent included home in the url in the ajax call? Would it be something to do with routing?

heres my javascript

```
                 function GetDevelopers() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'api/DeveloperApi',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");

    },
    error: function (data) {
        Alert("ERROR");
    }
});
}

  $(document).ready(function () {
GetDevelopers();
});
```

and my api

```
     public class DeveloperApiController : ApiController
{
    private IDeveloperRepository _repo;

    public DeveloperApiController(IDeveloperRepository _repo)
    {
        this._repo = _repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Developer> GetDevelopers()
    {
        return _repo.GetDevelopers();
    }
}
```

my api route which is the default

```
          config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: What are you requesting there or what should you get as a response?

Comment: Try calling the get method from browser or fiddler.

Comment: it seems a route problem, this might help www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjrheegKpSg

Comment: my response is some json. ive tested the api in the the browser http://localhost:59709/api/DeveloperApi and it works fine so im not sure whats the problem

Comment: Just a suggestion, when I get a 404 or whatever HTTP error, I go into an app like Fiddler, DHC or whatevs and send the request through there first. Afterwards I compare my requests.

Comment: @user2790781 please mention the full url like 'http://localhost:30245/api/DeveloperApi' just tell the localhost address exactly